# MySQL - Insert multiple rows based on column value

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor

I have the query working, just wondering if there is a better way to do this without cursors/loops/php side. I've been a DBA for 5+ years and just came across the := statement. Very cool.

Table (tblPeople) with the person ID and the number of tickets they bought.

```
PersonId  NumTickets
1         3  
2         1 
3         1
```

I then want to assign individual tickets to each person in a new table (tblTickets), depending on how many tickets they bought. The TicketId is a key, auto increment column.

```
TicketId  PersonId
100       1
101       1
102       1 
103       2
104       3
```

Here is the code. It loops through the whole tblPeople over and over again incrementing a new calculated column called rowID. Then I filter out the rows based on the number of tickets they bought in the WHERE clause. The problem I see is the subquery is huge, the more people I have, the bigger the subquery gets. Just not sure if there is a better way to write this.

```
INSERT INTO tblTickets (PersonId)
    SELECT PersonId
    FROM (
        SELECT s.PersonId, s.NumTickets,
            @rowID := IF(@lastPersonId = s.PersonId and @lastNumTickets = s.NumTickets, @rowID + 1, 0) AS rowID,
            @lastPersonId := s.PersonId,
            @lastNumTickets := s.NumTickets
        FROM tblPeople m,
            (SELECT @rowID := 0, @lastPersonId := 0, @lastNumTickets := 0) t
            INNER JOIN tblPeople s 
        ) tbl
    WHERE rowID < NumTickets
```

Comment: This seems like quote an odd schema.  The are assigning ticket id's after the fact based on aggregated ticket count information?  Why would you just not create ticket ID's as as they are added by the application (i.e. user buys 3 tickets and three rows are added with unique ID's for each)?

Comment: The actual ticketId numbers are irrelevant to the user. All they need to know is they bought x number of tickets, not the actual ticket number. I'm clearing out the tickets table each time I draw a number because I'll be drawing based on different conditions each time and I don't want any holes in the 'incremented key column' to keep the random() fair. Just the way random() works, if I have keys 1,2,3,4,10. If the random() picks 5-9, it will round up to 10 giving unfair odds.

Comment: Quoting [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html): “As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server.” So your query might break unexpectedly after some upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add a utility table `Numbers` which contains all the numbers from 1 up to the maximal number of tickets a person may buy. Then you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblTickets (PersonId)
SELECT s.PersonId
FROM tblPeople s, Numbers n
WHERE n.number <= s.NumTickets
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @MvG. I can't create triggers or sp because of the host, so this 'all query' is just a simple and perfect. I was making it harder in my mind with loops and cursors. Thanks again so much.

Answer (score 1):

Following Stored procedure will serve your purpose...

```
DELIMITER $$

USE <your database name> $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_ticket_value2`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `update_ticket_value2`()
BEGIN
DECLARE index_value INT;
DECLARE loop_variable INT;  


SET @KeyValue = 100;
SET @LastPersonID = 0;
SET @TicketNum = 0;

SET @PersonIDToHandle = 0;

SELECT @PersonIDToHandle = PersonID, @TicketNum = NumTickets
FROM tblPeople
WHERE PersonId > @LastPersonID
ORDER BY PersonId
LIMIT 0,1;

WHILE @PersonIDToHandle IS NOT NULL
DO
    SET loop_variable = 0;

    WHILE(loop_variable < @TicketNum) DO
        INSERT INTO tblTickets(TicketId, PersonId) VALUES(@KeyValue + loop_variable, @PersonIDToHandle);
        SET loop_variable = loop_variable + 1;
    END WHILE;  

    SET @LastPersonID = @PersonIDToHandle;
    SET @PersonIDToHandle = NULL;
    SET @KeyValue = @KeyValue + @TicketNum;

    SELECT @PersonIDToHandle := PersonID, @TicketNum := NumTickets
    FROM tblPeople
    WHERE PersonId > @LastPersonID
    ORDER BY PersonId
    LIMIT 0,1;
END WHILE;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Call the procedure as:

```
CALL update_ticket_value2();
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I can't use sp with my host. Has to be all query. @MvG posted a simple design.