# Finding syntax on how to duplicate entries based on the value of a filed in another table

Tags: mysql

The number of duplicate entries in table2 will depend on the table1(num_of_tickets) like in the example below, and the process will only start if the table(status) has a data of approved:

For example, with the table 1: (NOTE: This table will be inputted by the user, so it is always given)

| name | nDate | num_of_tickets | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| juan dela cruz | april 1, 2002 | 4 | Approved |
| maverick | December 7, 2020 | 5 | Unapproved |
| norman | may 3, 2001 | 2 | Approved |

The table 2 should be:

| name | date |
| --- | --- |
| juan dela cruz | april 1, 2002 |
| juan dela cruz | april 1, 2002 |
| juan dela cruz | april 1, 2002 |
| juan dela cruz | april 1, 2002 |
| norman | may 3, 2001 |
| norman | may 3, 2001 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Insert multiple rows based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208703/mysql-insert-multiple-rows-based-on-column-value)

Comment: You also need a trigger to recognise a change in status.